# Disposing of MemoryStream in Kinesis (KCL) C#

Tags: c#, amazon-kinesis

In AWS [Kinesis Client Library (KCL)](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net) there is a [sample producer](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net/blob/master/SampleProducer/SampleProducer.cs) that contains the following code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                PutRecordRequest requestRecord = new PutRecordRequest();
                requestRecord.StreamName = myStreamName;
                requestRecord.Data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testData-" + j));
                requestRecord.PartitionKey = "partitionKey-" + j;
                PutRecordResult putResult = kinesisClient.PutRecord(requestRecord);
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
                    String.Format("Successfully putrecord {0}:\n\t partition key = {1,15}, shard ID = {2}",
                        j, requestRecord.PartitionKey, putResult.ShardId));
            }
```

Why is the MemoryStream left like that? Shouldn't they be disposing of the stream? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryStream` does not need to be disposed because it does not hold onto unmanaged resources. It is a good habit to still dispose it just so that any disposable resource is disposed by convention. It is OK not to do that if that would make the code awkward. This is safe and not a code smell.